# Mysql get top half of table then bottom half of table

Tags: mysql

I need to get the **top half** of my table in my first query and in the next query I need the **bottom half.**

I tried doing this for the top but it wont work

```
SELECT * FROM t_domains WHERE type_domain='radio' ORDER BY 
date_created DESC LIMIT 0, (COUNT(*) / 2)
```

I need it as two queries for my function to work.

Anybody have any pointers or tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest doing 2 query's:

```
select count(*) from t_domains
```

to get the total count, and then get the data you want by using limit and offset:

```
select * from t_domains limit count/2
```

for the top and

```
select * from t_domains offset count/2
```

for the lower half......

This approach gives you also a way to limit the query's in another situation: what if the table contains 1 million records?

Comment: I tried this solution, but the response is:
`Undeclared variable: count`

Answer (score 1):

for first half

```
 mysql-> SET @n := 0

 mysql-> SELECT *,nnn FROM (
         SELECT *, @n := @n + 1 AS nnn  FROM t_domains   ORDER BY date_created 
         ) AS t
         WHERE nnn <=  ( SELECT COUNT(date_created) / 2  FROM t_domains  ) AND type_domain =    'radio'
```

for second half, change here  **WHERE nnn <=** this "<" on this ">"

Answer (score 1):

As [explained](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) in MySQL's official documentation, `LIMIT`'s two arguments must both be **CONSTANTS** except for prepared statements and stored programs. It does not seem very easy to simply store the count and later use it in a `LIMIT` clause.

As of version 8.0, MySQL has provided a [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) function, which provides a much simpler solution than other answers have pointed out.

```sql
set @count=(select count(*)/2 from t_domains);

select * from (
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by date_created desc) as row_num 
from t_domains
) as t
where row_num <= @count
;
```

You may also check [`RANK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank), which considers rows with equal values to have the same "ranking".

Answer (score 0):

This always works.

Store the count

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_domains WHERE type_domain='radio'
```

Then use the stored count.

```
SELECT * FROM t_domains WHERE type_domain='radio' ORDER BY 
date_created DESC LIMIT 0, {$stored_count/2}
```